# Get Visual Basic line number and use in messagebox

Tags: .net, line-numbers

I am constantly chasing errors in my code and I place message boxes in stating "Line xyz value = " etc.

But when I change my code I am constantly having to push the numbers and can't find them when I am finished or miss one here and there.

Just out of curiosity, but when the error flags in the JIT debugger it can tell me the module and the line number. Does anyone know if I can obtain that so that as the line numbers change so will my messagebox?

This would be a fantastic help. The reason I ask is because I am programming in AutoCAD and have no ability to debug in real time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "error" when you wrote "chasing errors" - are you referring to _thrown exceptions_ - or non-exceptional logic errors that doesn't cause abnormal program execution (i.e. non-fatal bugs)?

Comment: Also, I can assure you that you don't need to put your own line-numbers in your code - just use `Environment.StackTrace` - provided you compiled with full symbols (`*.pdb`) then it will contain the line-number of the caller's call-site to `Environment` in the penultimate line.

Comment: Oh, and there's also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute?view=net-6.0

Comment: This article is for VB.NET specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information

Comment: This is an awful way to make progress, google "debug .net autocad add-in" to get ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CallerLineNumberAttribute` as an attribute on a parameter for a `MsgBox` wrapper.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information

```
Public Shared Module MyFunctions

    Public Sub MsgBoxWithLineNumber( msg As String, <CallerFilePath> Optional  file As String = Nothing, <CallerLineNumber> Optional  lineNumber As Integer = 0)
        
        Dim msg2 As String = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & file & vbCrLf & "Line " & lineNumber
        MessageBox.Show( msg2, "Error" )
        
    End Sub

End Module
```

For example:

```
Public Sub Foobar()

    MsgBoxWithLineNumber( "foobar" )
    

End Sub
```

Will give you this Message box:

```
---------------------------
Hi
---------------------------
hello



C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad6\_voxwvlsv\sonnkr\LINQPadQuery.vb

Line 81
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Screenshot proof (via Linqpad):

[image]

Comment: Champion. Thank you so much. While the other suggestions were good, the process of starting and debugging through Visual Basic wasn't working the way I want.